# How to find a contour for a specified point using Autocad COM API?

Tags: python, autocad

My task is to find a contour (closed area) by specifying a point in a coordinate system.

Similar functionality is performed by the _-BOUNDARY command in Autocad, but interacting with the command interface is a slow solution when working with large data.

So I want to use Autocad's COM API (i.e. Autocad's object model), but I don't know what methods I can use to do this.

[image: example]

I am working in python, so please suggest your solutions using pyautocad, win32com.client or comtypes.

Comment: Can you not also call that same command from pyautocad or the COM API?

Comment: @mkrieger1, Sure I can do it, but the process of interacting with the command interface itself is a slow method for handling a lot of data. Either interaction with COM API (i.e. Autocad object model) or long agony in programming without it is suitable for me

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify which specific difficulty you have encountered while you were using one of these APIs.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot use the _-BOUNDARY command from the COM interface? And it's still not clear to me why you can't get this functionality from pyautocad, this would seem like the more straightforward solution.

Comment: @mkrieger1,Commands and the API are different things. There is a SendCommand method in the API that allows you to send any command, but I don't need it. I need to get the point contour from other autocad api methods.

Comment: So if there is a command `_-BOUNDARY` that does this, and you have a method `SendCommand` which can send a command, why can't you do `SendCommand(_-BOUNDARY)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I've answered this question several times already - I'm not comfortable with any way of interacting through teams. In my code there will be only a point, and by this point the code will calculate the loop in which this point is located

Comment: If you’re working with AutoCAD 2021 or later, you can use function Ed.Editor.traceBoundary()
In project https://github.com/CEXT-Dan/PyRx

Otherwise, I would look and see if shapely has something, you may be able to create Polygons or MultiPolygons from polyline coords and search for one that contains your point

Comment: @danielm103, I can't find this function in the repository

Comment: @danielm103, how exactly to use this function in python? help please.

Comment: @BobbyLith FYI, this may not be what you need. it’s not the COM API, but python wrappers around native ObjectARX. you will need to load the runtime into AutoCAD.
It’s in process. You will need to read through and figure out how to install it 

https://pyarx.blogspot.com/2024/03/traceboundary-sample-in-python-for.html